Can't Search Within Folders on a Drive?
I have a weird Spotlight issue with one of my external drives; I can search the drive as a whole just fine, but if I try to search only a specific folder within it then the search simply doesn't work.
To give an example, let's say I had a file /Volumes/MyDrive/Pictures/Image.png, if I run:
mdfind -onlyin /Volumes/MyDrive '*.png'
The results will include the file exactly as I expect. However if I instead run the following:
mdfind -onlyin /Volumes/MyDrive/Pictures '*.png'
It instead returns nothing, even though the image is in that folder, and it's definitely known to Spotlight (it is returned in the correct path when searching at a higher level).
This issue seems to apply to searching any folder within the drive, no matter how nested, it affects newly created folders and so-on so it shouldn't be an issue with permissions or extended attributes (as a new folder should have default permissions and no extended attributes).
I've already tried re-creating the index via the following:
sudo mdutil -i off /Volumes/MyDrive
sudo mdutil -X /Volumes/MyDrive
sudo mdutil -i on /Volumes/MyDrive

After the second step I also verified that the .Spotlight-V100 folder had been fully removed from the drive, so when indexing is turned on the index should be created 100% fresh.
However the exact same issue continues after indexing is complete; for whatever reason I just cannot search inside any folders, all my searches have to be of the entire drive (or my entire Mac) or they won't return anything within the drive at all.
Anyone have any other suggestions about what I can try to fix this? Why in the heck would Spotlight work fine with -onlyin for the drive, but not a folder within it? It's such a bizarre issue!

Your searches are looking for the string '*.png' in the file content or metadata. But, you appear to want to search by name. If so: mdfind -onlyin /Volumes/MyDrive -name 'png'

*.png is a valid search string, it'll search for any file with a name ending in .png, but I think maybe you're missing the problem – the search works fine at the drive's root, but returns nothing for a directory inside it (even if that's where the matching files are).

Are you trying to use mdfind to search by file name?

@Gilby I'm just giving a simple example that demonstrates the problem, I feel like you're fixating on the query but the query is not the problem here, you could change it to kind:image or whatever and the same problem occurs.
The problem is that a query that works for the drive's root folder (or system wide) does not work within sub-directories, even though these contain the files it should be finding.

For me, your mdfind behaves as expected and correctly finds files with the string *.png in the content when onlyin is the specific folder.  You have confused the issue by talking about finding files with names ending in .png - your commands don't do that.

@Gilby on macOS Sonoma that's exactly what the command does; it finds files ending in .png, I wouldn't have posted a command that doesn't work in either case, the problem is that it only works in one of them, so it has nothing to do with the use of *.png as the query string.
